# Bound on the number of bridges between vertices in a sampled subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I am researching connectivity in sampled subgraphs and have come across the following problem.

A bridge between two vertices $a$ and $b$ of a graph $G$ is an edge $e$ such that removing $e$ from $G$ disconnects $a$ and $b$. Note that $e$ is not a bridge if $a$ and $b$ are not connected in $G$. Denote by $B_G(a, b)$ the number of bridges between $a$ and $b$.

I am interested in how the number of bridges between $a$ and $b$ asymptotically distributes when sampling a random subgraph of $G$. More concretely, let $G=(V, E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, possibly with multiple edges. Now, sample each edge of $G$ independently with probability 1/2, yielding a new graph $G'$.

My question is: Is there a non-trivial function $g(n)$ and an $\ell>0$ such that 
$$P(\forall a, b\in V(G)\colon B_{G'}(a, b)<g(n))>1-n^{-\ell}$$
 for every choice of base graph $G$?

One example to note is the following. Sample the graph $G$ from $\mathcal G_{n, \frac 2n}$, i.e., the complete graph where each edge is sampled with probability $2/n$. Then the sampled subgraph $G'$ og $G$ is distributed according to $\mathcal G_{n, \frac1n}$. The latter has components of size $\Theta(n^{2/3})$ and I believe that each such component is fairly tree-like of diameter $\Theta(n^{1/3})$. In that case, this shows that we must have $g(n)= \Omega(n^{1/3})$.

Comment: Well for the complete graph, in order to have g(n)>0,  you need for at least $(n-3)$ vertex $x \neq a,b$ either the edge ax or bx not to be in G'. If this is not the case then $a,b$ are connected by two disjoint paths, hence $B_G'(a,b)$ =0. This has probability $(n-3)(\frac{3}{4})^{(n-3)}$, smaller than $n^{-\ell}$, for any $\ell$ as $n$ grows.

Comment: This is true. However, I would like to have some bound that works for every graph. I have edited my question to include an example, where there will be many bridges.